# Select all but exclude certain subchildren

Tags: xml, xpath

I simply would like to exclude a certain element (in the example, `exclude`) from my xpath select however my xpath is not working.

**XML**

```
 <root>
      <x>
        <y>
          <z>
            <exclude me="please"></exclude>
          </z>
        </y>
      </x>
      <x>
        <y>
          <z>
            <exclude me="please"></exclude>
          </z>
        </y>
      </x>
    </root>
```

**XPath:** 
`/*[not(self::exclude)]` Returns entire XML
`/*[node()!=exclude]` Returns entire XML
`/root//x//y//z/*[not(self::exclude)]` (this actually returns the very node I do not want)
+ many more iterations

I want the the return result to be:

```
    <root>
      <x>
        <y>
          <z>
          </z>
        </y>
      </x>
      <x>
        <y>
          <z>
          </z>
        </y>
      </x>
    </root>
```

At the very least I would like to select all but the `me` attribute. Is this possible? I am starting to come to the conclusion that it is not. Thank you.

---

BizTalk Code:

```
construct msgException{
msgException = msgReservationMultiPartIn.NewMessagePart;
xpath(msgException,"//*[not(self::exclude)]");
}
```

Comment: What environment do you use XPath in? Please show your code.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I am just testing the above statements on xpath online testers (I have tried multiple with this one)... I will be running this through BizTalk eventually.

Comment: What online testers exactly? What specific tool or site did return the `exclude` node for `/root//x//y//z/*[not(self::exclude)]`?

Comment: @MathiasMüller `http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester` : returns just the exclude nodes, `http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath` : returns nothing , `ww.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output` : returns nothing, `http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php` : returns nothing.

Comment: Now that you've edited the question: What does this Biztalk code return exactly?

Comment: @MathiasMüller it is returning the exact xml that I fed it, no differences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68247/discussion-between-mathias-muller-and-40alpha).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester returns the `exclude` element node as the result of

```
/root//x//y//z/*[not(self::exclude)]
```

You should never use it again. Also, as you have seen, three other sites returned nothing.

---

Your XPath expressions are sensible I'd say (well, some of them are). But you cannot see that very well - because the following happens: With an expression like

```
//*[not(self::exclude)]
```

the `exclude` node is really not selected at all. **But**: Those online testers return result nodes with all their content, so a simple expression like `/root` yields the whole XML file (at least with http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php).

For the expression `//*[not(self::exclude)]` the same XPath tester returns:

```
<root>
<x>
<y>
<z>
<exclude me="please"/>
</z>
</y>
</x>
<x>
<y>
<z>
<exclude me="please"/>
</z>
</y>
</x>
</root>
-----------------------
<x>
<y>
<z>
<exclude me="please"/>
</z>
</y>
</x>
-----------------------
<y>
<z>
<exclude me="please"/>
</z>
</y>
-----------------------
<z>
<exclude me="please"/>
</z>
-----------------------
<x>
<y>
<z>
<exclude me="please"/>
</z>
</y>
</x>
-----------------------
<y>
<z>
<exclude me="please"/>
</z>
</y>
-----------------------
<z>
<exclude me="please"/>
</z>
```

Individual results are separated by `--------`, and, as you can see, the `exclude` node does not appear in the results on its own - just as the by-product of its parent and ancestors being selected and returned.

**What does that mean?**

Develop your XPath expressions in parallel with the environment you use XPath in (in your case, if I have understood correctly, Biztalk). Then, if the wrong elements are returned, come back here, post the complete code and get help.

Comment: I might have accepted the answer a little too soon. However, I appreciate the overall take away that you outlined. After testing in my environment I am receiving the same result, exclude is included. I have updated my question with my actual code. Changing the node name to stay up to date with the example.

Comment: @40Alpha You're always free to un-accept my answer if there's another answer that you feel is more helpful. Also, if you have any comment on my answer or would like me to elaborate on something specific - I'm glad to extend my answer.