# Selecting nodes in between comments with xpath from xmldocument

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get nodes in between comments.

example:

```
<Name>
  <First>a</First>
  <Last>b</Last>
</Name>
<!-- family names -->
<Name>
  <First>c</First>
  <Last>d</Last>
</Name>
<Name>
  <First>e</First>
  <Last>f</Last>
</Name>
<Name>
  <First>g</First>
  <Last>h</Last>
</Name>
<!-- family ends -->
<!-- other names -->
<Name>
  <First>i</First>
  <Last>j</Last>
</Name>
<Name>
  <First>k</First>
  <Last>l</Last>
</Name>
<!-- other ends -->
```

I'd like to be able to select the nodes in between the comment family names and family ends. 
Tried several ways with xpath, but I cant get further then selecting all comment nodes. When I want to select comment nodes containing value x, I do not get any result. So I'm not sure how to continue.
for example:

```
var x = xml.SelectSingleNode("//comment()[contains('family names')]");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think between `[]`, you are expected to specify an index, not a predicate.

Comment: @GáborBakos No, that's not correct. Using `[` and `]` is the _only_ way to use a predicate.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Sorry, I remembered wrong. (Even in JSONPath the predicates should be within `[` and `]`, but with a further `?(` and `)`.) Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @GáborBakos No reason to apologize! I know people are just trying to help - and sometimes they themselves profit from it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What's wrong with your attempt?**

An expression like

```
//comment()[contains('family names')]
```

is not valid XPath. The `contains()` function expects two arguments, a first argument that is a string (or can be coerced into a string by computing the string value of a node) and a second one that is also a string. The following would have worked:

```
//comment()[contains(.,'family names')]
```

But that does not get you far yet, because once you've identified the starting comment, you need to find what comes after it.

**A correct XPath expression**

Use the following expression:

```
//comment()[contains(.,'family names')]/following::*[not(preceding::comment()[contains(.,'family ends')])]
```

which translates to

```
//comment()                         Find comment nodes anywhere in the documents
[contains(.,'family names')]        but only select them if they contain the text
                                    "family names"
/following::*                       Select all element nodes that follow those comments
[not(preceding::comment()           but only return them if they are not preceded by
                                    a comment node...
[contains(.,'family ends')])]       ...that contains the text "family ends".
```

Applied to a well-formed and more sensible input XML document:

**Input XML**

```
<root>
<Name>
  <First>NO</First>
  <Last>NO</Last>
</Name>
<!-- family names -->
<Name>
  <First>YES</First>
  <Last>YES</Last>
</Name>
<Name>
  <First>YES</First>
  <Last>YES</Last>
</Name>
<Name>
  <First>YES</First>
  <Last>YES</Last>
</Name>
<!-- family ends -->
<!-- other names -->
<Name>
  <First>NO</First>
  <Last>NO</Last>
</Name>
<Name>
  <First>NO</First>
  <Last>NO</Last>
</Name>
</root>
```

The result will be (individual results separated by `-------`):

**Output**

```
<Name>
<First>YES</First>
<Last>YES</Last>
</Name>
-----------------------
<First>YES</First>
-----------------------
<Last>YES</Last>
-----------------------
<Name>
<First>YES</First>
<Last>YES</Last>
</Name>
-----------------------
<First>YES</First>
-----------------------
<Last>YES</Last>
-----------------------
<Name>
<First>YES</First>
<Last>YES</Last>
</Name>
-----------------------
<First>YES</First>
-----------------------
<Last>YES</Last>
```

---

Whoever designed this XML document did not design it very cleverly, if you pardon my French. Relying on comments with a specific text in a specific position is very dangerous.

Comment: I know the design of the xml is ugly, though I'm going to have to use it. So thank you very much for making this possible! This is a great and complete answer!

Comment: Is it possible to get only the name nodes with the first and last inside. (So not the individual ones) Only the ones that are like <Name>
<First>YES</First>
<Last>YES</Last>
</Name>. So from your result excluding the single results seperated by -----------------------

Comment: @Rob You can use `//comment()[contains(.,'family names')]/following::Name[not(preceding::comment()[contains(.,'family ends')])]` to only get `Name` elements in the results. But they are likely sent to output _including_ all their descendants (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27788959/1987598)).

Comment: I found it eventualy last night. This is exactly what I  needed. Thanks again for your wonderful help!